# GL_FEEDBACK mode doesn't work on specific Windows platforms

Tags: windows, opengl

We've encountered a strange problem on newer laptops using built-in graphic cards.

In order to draw true-type fonts we obtain the glyph outlines using wglUseFontOutlines and then draw them with in `glRenderMode(GL_FEEDBACK)`.
Afterwards we parse the feedback buffer. This has worked for many years. 
Now we have a problem with glyphs containing holes (only on platforms with built-in graphic cards):

`wglUseFontOutlines` works perfectly. If we just draw the returned display lists, everything is fine. However, the token stream generated with `GL_FEEDBACK` is corrupt. The debugger shows nothing unusual, all functions return with success and the parsing itself works fine too. It is really the binary data generated by `GL_FEEDBACK` mode, which is wrong.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

And is there an alternative way to obtain outlines and fillings for true type fonts on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing into the blue here: The GL_SELECT and GL_FEEDBACK rendering modes were usually not supported by widespread GPU driver OpenGL implementations. Only a handful graphics cards from the previous century actually did support these rendering modes. Hence you would almost always fall back into a software implementation when using those modes.

However given modern GPU's vastly more flexible feedback mechanisms, the latest drivers could actually try to implement those rendering modes using GPU features (somewhat weird, because those modi have been removed from modern OpenGL profiles). Anyway, this could be the reason why you're experiencing these problems.

> In order to draw true-type fonts we obtain the glyph outlines using wglUseFontOutlines and then draw them with in glRenderMode(GL_FEEDBACK). Afterwards we parse the feedback buffer.

That's a cool Rube-Goldberg machine. Why don't you simply cut the middleman and obtain the glyph outlines directly using the appropriate Windows GDI functions ([GetGlyphOutline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) for this? This is what wglUseFontOutlines is using internally anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am also aware of GetGlyphOutline. But wouldn't I have to replace the "feedback middleman" with another one? Unless I miss something, GetGlyphOutline gives me Bezier curves only, so I have to convert them to lines, haven't I?

Comment: @Nimo: OpenGL does process lines only as well, so you actually have two middlemen with wglFontOutlines: A curve tesselator and then OpenGL. Instead you should go into a curve tesselator directly.